# Make phpMyAdmin work as alias in Nginx + PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, fedora

The system is Fedora 25, with Nginx 1.10.2 and PHP 7.0.14 work in CGI Mode.

I using dnf to install phpMyAdmin, the location is **/usr/share/phpMyAdmin**, so I try to let it work as alias in multi-website.

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
    include fastcgi_php.conf;
}
```

And I add the location into open_basedir.

```
fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=$document_root/:/tmp/:/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/:/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/:/etc/phpMyAdmin/:/usr/share/php:/usr/bin/pear:/dev/null:/var/lib/php";
```

I open the URL and the log show this message:

```
2016/12/19 17:52:05 [error] 2241#0: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/phpmyadmin/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 1.1.1.1, server:1.1.1.1 , request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"
```

How to make it correct and work? Thank you!

Update:

I think maybe cause by **fastcgi_param**, in order to solve the blank page problem in PHP fastcgi, I add 2 line into this file.

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections 2048;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;

    charset UTF-8;
    sendfile on;
    send_timeout 10;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    server_tokens off;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_body_buffer_size 256k;
    open_file_cache max=102400 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**fastcgi_php.conf:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**website.conf:**

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name test.domain.com;
root /var/www/site1;
index index.html index.php;
access_log /var/log/site1-access.log combined;
error_log /var/log/site1-error.log warn;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /error.html;
    include fastcgi_php.conf;
}

location /phpmyadmin {
    alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
    include fastcgi_php.conf;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It would work but *No such file or directory*. Nginx **can't find the index.php in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/phpmyadmin/** because the folder doesn't exists.

> You have to edit the alias path of phpmyadmin location (see code snippet how I did). After that go to **/usr/share/** path and **rename the folder phpMyAdmin** to **phpmyadmin** (lowercase) or use the same notation in Location (e.g. Location /phpMyAdmin)

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name test.domain.com;
   root /var/www/site1;
   index index.html index.php;

   # Configure Access and Error Logging
   access_log /var/log/site1-access.log combined;
   error_log /var/log/site1-error.log warn;

   # Configure SSL Certification usage
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;
   ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_session_timeout 10m;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   # Add Headers for security purposes
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

   # Define some page rules
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /error.html;
       include fastcgi_php.conf;
   }

   location /phpmyadmin {
       alias /usr/share;
       include fastcgi_php.conf;
   }

   location = /robots.txt {
       allow all;
       log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
   }

   location ~ /\. {
       deny all;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I know it, I try to copy the /usr/share/phpMyAdmin to the site directory and it works perfectly. but I want to let Nginx alias to /usr/share/phpMyAdmin so every site can use phpMyAdmin directly without making a copy.

Comment: Try to rename the folder phpMyAdmin in /usr/share/ to phpmyadmin (lowercase) and edit the alias to "alias /usr/share;" I think this could work

Comment: Still wrong, log show Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php (No such file or directory).

Comment: Can you post the current version of your nginx file?

Comment: Update the question with configuration yet.